# Loading entire Json blob as is from S3 in AWS Redshift using COPY gives error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, jsonpath

I am trying to load S3 data into redshift using COPY command using following jsonPaths

```
{
    _meta-id : 1,
    payload: {..}
}
```

In my redshift table, I want to store entire JSON doc as my second column

```
{
    "jsonpaths": [
        "$['_meta-id']",
        "$"
    ]
}
```

This gives error
Invalid JSONPath format. Supported notations are 'dot-notation' and 'bracket-notation': $

```
Query:

copy table_name
from 's3://abc/2018/12/15/1' 
json 's3://xyz/jsonPaths';


[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Invalid JSONPath format. Supported notations are 'dot-notation' and 'bracket-notation': $..
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Invalid JSONPath format. Supported notations are 'dot-notation' and 'bracket-notation': $
  code:      8001
  context:   
  query:     21889
  location:  s3_utility.cpp:672
  process:   padbmaster [pid=11925]
  -----------------------------------------------;
1 statement failed.
```

Can someone help?

Comment: It will help if you post your actual COPY statement and the full error message.

Comment: Updated above post